# How can i unset the for and foreach loop value in php

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

My html code is:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="pro_code_table">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="12" class="pro_code_lable_with_data">Product Code Detailes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table_val_data">Title</td>
    @foreach($x as $k_x => $v_x)
        <td class="table_val_data">{{ $v_x }}</td>  
    @endforeach
    </tr>
    <tr>
    @foreach ($y as $k_y => $v_y) 
        <td class="table_val_data">{{ $v_y }}</td>
    <?php $pro_code_count=count($pro_code);
    //print_r($pro_code);
    ?>
    @for($r = 1; $r <=sizeof($x); $r++)
        <td>
        <?php $i=1; ?>
        @foreach($pro_code as $key=>$val)
        @if($i % 2 != 0)
          <input type="text" name="pro_code[]" value="{{ $val }}">
        @else
          <input type="text" name="pro_code[]" value="{{ $val }}">
        @endif
        @endforeach
        <?php 
        $i++;
        ?>
        </td>
        @endfor
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

In that i can loop data inside table, the X and Y axis looped correctly, but inside an `<td>` datas are looped more then one time,

nw how can i stop the looping process

my o\p is looking like below

[image]

i want data like an below like that

[image]

Comment: hi bjoern, hw can u edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" class="pro_code_table">
<tr>
<th colspan="12" class="pro_code_lable_with_data">Product Code Detailes</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="table_val_data">Title</td>
@foreach($x as $k_x => $v_x)
<td class="table_val_data">{{ $v_x }}</td>
@endforeach            
</tr>

<tr>
@foreach($y as $k_y_t=> $v_y_t)
<td class="table_val_data">{{ $v_y_t }}</td>

@foreach($y as $k_y=> $v_y)
    @foreach($x as $k_x => $v_x)
    @if($k_y_t==$k_y)
        <td class="table_val_data">
    @foreach($pro_code as $k_pro_code=> $v_pro_code)            
    <?php
    if($k_x.'-'.$k_y==$k_pro_code){
        echo '<input type="text" name="value" value="'.$v_pro_code.'">';
    }                   
    ?>
    @endforeach             
    </td>
    @endif    
    @endforeach 
@endforeach 
</tr>

@endforeach
</table>

$x: {"3":"bule","4":"green"}
$y: {"5":"cotten","6":"polyester"}
$pro_code_in_edit: {"3-5":"12","4-5":"23","3-6":"56","4-6":"89"}
```

[image]